# Reference in Python

Tags: python, reference

I have this code :

```
doc = parse('sites.xml')
sites = []
for item in doc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("site"):
    try:
        site = Site()
        site.name = item.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        site.start = item.getElementsByTagName("start")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        site.end = item.getElementsByTagName("end")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        site.Id = item.getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        sites.append(site)
    except:
        pass
for l in range(len(sites)):
    print(site.name + ' ' + site.start + ' ' + site.end + ' ' + site.Id)
```

I got the last line repeated on output. I don't know why the value of `site` has changed. Normally at every iteration I create a new reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating `len(sites)` times, but never assign anything to `site`; it is still bound to the last value bound in the previous loop.

Just loop over `sites` **directly**:

```
for site in sites:
    print(site.name + ' ' + site.start + ' ' + site.end + ' ' + site.Id)
```

Using a `range(len(sites))` loop is still possible, albeit un-pythonic and needlessly verbose; you'd have to use the generated index to bind `site` each loop iteration with:

```
for l in range(len(sites)):
    site = sites[l]
    print(site.name + ' ' + site.start + ' ' + site.end + ' ' + site.Id)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second `for` loop (`for l in range...`) you're not getting the `site` instance. You're getting an index and storing it in `l` (which gives you an int), but you're never using that index to retrieve the `site` instance from the `sites` list so the variable `site` is still pointing to the last `site` created on your first `for` loop.

Try:

```
for l in range(len(sites)):
    site=sites[l]
    print(site.name + ' ' + site.start + ' ' + site.end + ' ' + site.Id)
```

or even better

```
for site in sites:
    print(site.name + ' ' + site.start + ' ' + site.end + ' ' + site.Id)
```